# Vim Can't Save File (E212)

Tags: macos, vim

Sometimes when I create a file using `vim some/path/newfile`, vim lets me edit it, only to complain when I attempt to save my changes.

```
E212 Can't open file for writing.
```

This appears to happen only when the new file is located in a system directory.

`:w!` does not override this error.

How can I write the current buffer, without having to save it to a temporary location, exit, then rename it using sudo?

Comment: Also, sometimes if you put a space between `w` and `!`, it works. (At least this works for me in linux using heavier vim `vim-gtk` not just lightweight `vim` although I'm sure it would work just the same in regular ole' vim.) I didn't know about `Peter`'s answer, though. `w!!` works for me, too.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This will ask you for the root password, then save your changes as you requested:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Then type (L)oad at the prompt, to re-load the file after it is saved.

Comment: This worked! Maybe it could be combined with @Peter's answer to create a vim alias in the .vimrc file?

Comment: it says me "shell returned 1"

Comment: I just get an operation not permitted error when trying this in WSL running ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 20):

You can *mkdir* first, then save it.

Comment: This does not help. The question is not about directories that don't exist. It's about editing existing files as (for example) a normal user, when the file can be written by root only. In that case, there is no missing directory to create.

Comment: I found this answer helpful because I had the same question as the OP and didn't realize that not only was my file I was trying to write into new, but a directory in my path was new also. mkdir solves the issue if this is your case.

Answer (score 19):

Add this line to your `.vimrc`:

```
cmap w!! %!sudo tee > /dev/null
```

and then you can do

```
:w!!
```

when you get into this position, and it will write the file using sudo. Very handy.

Comment: I like this idea. Typing :w!! replaces the command with `!sudo tee > /dev/null`, but it just says n "lines filtered" and the file is not actually created. It appears that the /dev/null is causing that?

Comment: Great idea -- `w!!` is much easier to remember than my solution. What works for me on OS X is `cmap w!! %!sudo tee %`

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid this problem by using "sudo" to start the editing session.

```
sudo vi name-of-file
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a robust, easy-to-remember solution and don't mind installing a plugin, try [SudoEdit.vim - Edit Files using sudo or su or any other tool](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709).

Answer (score 3):

If this is the case in Windows 7 or later editions, run the VI editor as Administrator. Right Click of the application and select "Run as Administrator". This issue will be resolved. Moreover, the error is due to Administrative Privileges.

Answer (score 3):

## vim some/path/newfile

you can try to do it in two steps,first create the folder 'some' and 'path' by use mkdir ~ ;second you go into the 'path' folder,use the command:sudo vim newfile.then save it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the directory where you are trying to save the file exists and that you have permission to edit the file.

You can type `:help message` in Vim to get more information on this and other error messages. Try searching by typing `/E212` once the docs come up. You can also view the documentation online at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/message.html and CTRL-F to find it.

Comment: In particular, sometimes vim changes the current working directory of your buffer. In that case, an intermediate directory might not exist and that's what causes E212. You need to change the current directory back using `:cd ORIGINAL_FOLDER_PATH` to resolve this and be able to save again.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you may also want to ensure you have sufficient storage in the partition where you're attempting to save the file. I had to free up some space in my /home drive and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is what fixed it for me. Your file might be set to immutable meaning that you can't edit it.

You can check this with `lsattr /path/to/file.txt`

If it is use
`chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` to make it no longer immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue outside of system directory.
When I tried to open a file `vim src/help/tips.c`. Turns out `help` directory did not exist, the directory was named differently and it was one of those very rare occasions that I did not auto-complete with `Tab`.

So, in conclusion, if this happens for a file that is not at a place where you may have permission issues, look if the path leading up to the file is a valid one.

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced this in Kali!! The default account requires escalation to root with "sudo" in order for the file to be editable.
e.g: sudo vim / at this point all standard expectations appear to follow.

Comment: Your answer doesn't currently answer the question, as the OP was asking how to save without having to exit VIM.