# why :w filename is not working to write file in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, vim-plugin

I was watching a tutorial in which instructor using vim for ruby on rials development. He writes code on blank screen and then uses command **:w hello.rb**  the whole code behaves like ruby code... when i try to use this command it gives an error message. I searched a lot on stackoverflow.com 
There are some similar questions but no one works...
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Saving_a_file
and
[Vim Can't Save File (E212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948441/vim-cant-save-file-e212)
and one solutions is **:w!!** but i want to save file as :w filename e.g :w hello.rb

Comment: “it gives an error message”—what error message it gives?

Comment: What is ruby on rials?

Comment: what is the reason of vote down? it is just a question?

Comment: Down vote is because there are plenty of ways that saving a file can fail. You said "gives an error message" without saying what the error message was. Without the specific error, nobody can tell you why writing the file failed. So here's another downvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following (after pressing escape) :wq!
Should work.

Comment: file name is hello.rb so it means :wq! hello.rb or simple :wq!?

Comment: vi hello.rb will either edit the existing file or create a new one. Then :wq! To save and quit. Simple :)

Comment: If your error message is due to permissions, try: sudo vi hello.rb instead of vi hello.rb