# Can't write ./config file for installing NIX

Tags: vim, nix, system.configuration

I'm trying to install NIX to run a software called ARTIQ and am following the instructions given in this page.

https://m-labs.hk/artiq/manual/installing.html#installing-via-nix-linux

I am required to provide a cryptographic signature by amending the ~/.config/nix/nix.conf file. After opening the file using `sudo vi ~/.config/nix/nix.conf` and amending it, I can't perform

```
:w!
```

it says "can't open file for writing"
Could someone please advise me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim Can't Save File (E212)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948441/vim-cant-save-file-e212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the directories `~/.config/` and `~/.config/nix/` exist? I suspect one of them or both don't. Exit without saving (`:qa!`) and create the directories:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/nix
```

Then edit again:

```
vi ~/.config/nix/nix.conf
```

PS. Do not use `sudo` to edit files in your `$HOME`.